# Rotating text with CSS3/HTML5

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a `<span>` that I want to rotate. I am using HTML5, CSS3, and Internet Explorer 9.

I tried the below CSS, but it's not working:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

How do I rotate the span?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-webkit-` and `-moz-` properties are for webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) and Gecko browsers (Firefox) respectively.

You need to use the equivalent for IE as well.

```
.rotate {

/* Safari, Chrome */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Older versions of IE */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

/* CSS3 standard as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/ */
transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
```

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/)

Comment: Also adding the non prefixed version for when the spec is finalized is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Try `-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);`

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements can't be rotated. you have to display them as block level.