# After rotation a box the box is different. (css transform preserve-3d rotate)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'am trying to rotate a box with text like a slot-machine. I use pure css.
I think it works so far but i do have a problem that the rotated-box is smaller after rotation.
Here is my code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg4w7/4/)

The main-code is done here:

```
#category_wrapper.show-unten{
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-5px) rotateX(90deg);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);
  transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);

}
```

Is this a bug or do I something wrong?

Comment: They look the same to me. 211x106 in Chrome inspector. Also, in your `-webkit-transform`, `translateZ` is `-5px` and not `-75px`.

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/Yg4w7/7/ but in firefox it is still smaller

Comment: just for info my answer was only on fire fox to do it for all browsers  check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026200/rotating-text-with-css3-html5?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only use this:

```
#category_wrapper.show-unten{
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-5px) rotateX(90deg);
-moz-transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);
-ms-transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);
-o-transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg);
transform: translateZ(0px) rotateX(90deg);

}
```

the changes at last line see==> transform: translateZ(0px) rotateX(90deg);

and use this:

```
transform: rotateX(-100deg) translateZ(75px); //instead of -90 deg in class .unten
```

i updated your jsfiddle =>[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moathhowari/Yg4w7/10/)