# is it possible to make a diagonal menu bar using css?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, menubar, diagonal

I wanted to make a diagonal menu bar for my blog but I just can't figure out how to do it. can any of you help please?

Something simple (like the one in the picture) that I can personalize myself according to my template :

[image]

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026200/rotating-text-with-css3-html5) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible to do that. You should be looking at this CSS3 property, `transform`, and then specify how much degree you want it to rotate.

Example

```
#myMenuBar {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```

Just be aware of the browser support when it comes to `transform`. You can find more details here:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score -1):

This section is not for jobs you want other people to do. This is the question section, where you can ask people to help you with your code that isn't working or is giving you a bug. I recommend posting this in the job section. 
Best Regards

Comment: I wasn't aware there was such a category, besides, I already have a code, but no matter what trick I tried I couldn't figure out what was wrong... I'only a beginner after all

Comment: Its fine, and I understand. Have you tried just rotating the div?